# How to ReverseMap a complex object in AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

Here is the `CreateMap` method:

```
        Mapper.CreateMap<Domain.Models.Organization, OrganizationInputModel>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Address1, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Address.Address1))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Address2, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Address.Address2))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.City, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Address.City))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.State, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Address.State))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Zip, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Address.Zip))
            .ReverseMap();
```

Here `Address` is a complex object.

I was expecting to see the bi-directional model mapping. But it turns out the complex object mapping is broken:

```
var entity = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<Domain.Models.Organization>(model);
```

I got an error:

> {"message":"Null value for non-nullable member. Member: 'Address'."}

---

Some SO posts says reverse mapping is only for simple object, and we will have to create two `Mapper.CreateMap` in this case. Is it really so?

Comment: Yes, you need to define the reverse mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to create the reverse mapping in this case. The reason for this is because AutoMapper wouldn't know how to instantiate the target `Address` property.